# не работает expiresIn, когда генерирую jwt токен

Tags: javascript, jwt

Не получается установить время действия токена, при выводе токена он меняется каждую секунду.

```
jwt.sign({nameuser, surnameuser, mailuser}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: "7d"})
```

Comment: вы каждую секунду генерируете новый jwt, каждому jwt вычисляется время жизни относительно момента его создания, а момент создания меняется раз вы генерируете каждую секунду

Comment: Разобрался, чтобы проверить, что токен еще жив нужно использовать jwt.verify

Comment: вы прочитайте вопрос, который вы написали. вы написали о том, что ваша цель - проверить жив ли токен?